# Highlighting and Annotating text in pdf programmatically

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I have a pdf for piping and instrument diagram (P&ID) something like this https://creativeengineers.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/CEI-PID-Sample-Rev4.pdf

I need to:

1. Find text (tag numbers) in the P&ID based on a set of strings I have in a text file (e.g. PI 4507, PT 4509, etc.). This list can have 100s of strings to be searched.
2. Then I need to highlight and encircle (or enrectangle) the matched texts in the P&ID pdf.
3. Finally, annotate those highlighted texts in the pdf with some meta info associated from the text file I used in #1 (like adding name, link, etc.)

All this needs to be done programmatically.

I know 2 py libraries pdf-annotate and Py2PDF but I am not sure if they will solve the purpose.

If anyone of you has worked on a similar problem, could you please point me to the tools which are required to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file already has much of that info supposedly added half century ago ! clearly an error on my part in analysis! since file was built 2019 and modified 119 times since. What I can not understand is why it is some text and not others, the P3 must have had a filter setting based on some parameter. IF I look at another sample from the same period it also has that same odd split of some text is tagged (and invisible) but other text is not. [***Later edit***] This appears to be deliberate by Autodesk to ensure vector shx text is searchable see https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Drawing-text-appears-as-Comments-in-a-PDF-created-by-AutoCAD.html

It may be better to use one same method all over the text layer in a clean file plot without partially annotated text since the first viewer I used only saw 5 out of the 119 annotations.

[image]

The highly complex structure encourages me to suggest it may be easier to work with the source since annotation text is currently spread across many different content groups.

Here is the target so luckily there seems to be a PI and 4507 closely related

```
0 -1 1 0 9546 14389 Tm
0 Tc
84.96094 Tz 0 Tr
(PI) Tj
ET
/F1 96.928 Tf
BT
0 -1 1 0 9413 14442 Tm
0 Tc
84.96094 Tz 0 Tr
(4507) Tj
ET
12 w EMC /OC /oc2 BDC
```

You asked how to add annotations in bulk, so although this is 2 of your hundred, you just need to expand this 196 more times. So annotation data is a variation of Forms Data, thus to add in bulk it is exactly the same base process, you add the Tag/Value data pairs via an FDF file which then opens with all annotation in any conforming PDF read/editor such as Acrobat Reader, Tracker X-change or Foxit. For more details including ***"Export comments to AutoCAD" (or Word)*** see Adobe Help they refer to the task as merging comments https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/importing-exporting-comments.html#importing_and_exporting_comments

> You can also import comments from a Forms Data Format (FDF) file or an XFDF file, which is an XML-based FDF file. You cannot open and view FDF files or XFDF files on their own.

[image]

```
%FDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<<
/FDF <<
/Annots [2 0 R 3 0 R 4 0 R 5 0 R]
/F (CEI-PID-Sample-Rev4annots.pdf)
/UF (CEI-PID-Sample-Rev4annots.pdf)
>>
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/C [1 1 0]
/Contents (PI 4507 which is attached to valve HV-4507)
/F 4
/M (D:20220614000000Z)
/NM (49fb01d8-8e74-4ead-a4c684bddfbdaa96)
/Page 0
/Popup 3 0 R
/QuadPoints [581 866 581 860 573 866 573 860 573 869 573 857 565 869 565 857]
/Rect [565 857 581 869]
/Subtype /Highlight
/Type /Annot
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/F 28
/M (D:20220614000000Z)
/NM (afdaf61c-030a-4303-b1e69f90199a6b7f)
/Open false
/Page 0
/Parent 2 0 R
/Rect [581.099976 -75.600006 738.299988 0]
/Subtype /Popup
/Type /Annot
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/C [1 1 0]
/Contents (PT 4509 near PI 4507)
/F 4
/M (D:20220614000000Z)
/NM (189e672d-3045-405a-94c3198c148b9b98)
/Page 0
/Popup 5 0 R
/QuadPoints [610 893 610 886 603 893 603 886 602 896 602 884 595 896 595 884]
/Rect [595 884 610 896]
/Subtype /Highlight
/Type /Annot
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/F 28
/M (D:20220614000000Z)
/NM (c1987509-db8f-44f6-bdc754bb04c68ab8)
/Open false
/Page 0
/Parent 4 0 R
/Rect [612.58252 -75.600006 769.782532 0]
/Subtype /Popup
/Type /Annot
>>
endobj
trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
>>
%%EOF
```

so colour is `/C [1 1 0]` (yellow)

Comment `/Contents (Text to appear in comment)`

Random Comment NuMonic `/NM ....`

Page is base zer0 `/Page 0`

The XY values for where to float are your main issue as I don't do python its usually too many reams of code. Personally I would bypass this official program method and use simpler AHK scripting of keys.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this is just a representative file. Actual files don't have this much annotation info already, it is just a plain pdf file. On which I need to:
1. Find text (tag numbers) in the P&ID based on a set of strings I have in a text file (e.g. PI 4507, PT 4509, etc.). This list can be 100s of strings. 
2. Highlight and encircle (or enrectangle) the matched texts in the P&ID pdf.
3. Annotate those highlighted texts in the pdf with some meta info associated from the text file I used in #1 (like adding name, link, etc.)
All this to be done programmatically.

Comment: @DaveSB *"But this is just a representative file. Actual files don't have this much annotation info already, it is just a plain pdf file."* - Then that file is not really representative: A representative file should in particular trigger the issues one can run into. How difficult can it get in your _actual files_ to find text?

Comment: @mkl Hi. The intention is to accomplish all the 3 tasks programmatically on a pdf. I have 10s of pdf files with 50 tags in each file. I don't want to control find, highlight and annotate them manually.